# What is the significance of the gifts that Eliezer gave to Rivka?

Tags: gifts, parashat-chaye-sara, imahot-matriarch-mothers, eliezer

The verse states ([24:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#v=22)):

> ויקח האיש נזם זהב בקע משקלו ושני צמידים על ידיה עשרה זהב משקלם
>
> the man took a golden nose ring, weighing half [a shekel], and two
>   bracelets for her hands, weighing ten gold [shekels].

What, if any, is the significance of these particular gifts and their weights?

Comment: I've [answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but I'd like to see what other people have to say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rashi there](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#showrashi=true&v=22) says:

- The half shekel weight of the nose-ring is a reference to the מחצית השקל, the half shekel coin that Jews donated to the Temple yearly.
- The bracelets refer to the ten tablets -- the two bracelets are the two tablets, and the weight of 10 shekels corresponds to the Ten Commandments.

*Tol'dos Yitzchak* (by Rav Yitzchak Karo, uncle of the Bes Yosef) [h/t msh210] and Targum Yonasan ben Uziel (seen [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=299)) agree with Rashi, quoted above.

Comment: _Tol'dos Yitzchak_ (_Rav Yitzchak_ Karo, uncle of the _Bes Yosef_) agrees. (Of course, he significantly postdated _Rashi_.)

Comment: Rabbi Soloveichik observed that a would-be convert is asked two general questions: "do you agree to keep the commandments?" and "do you want to belong to the Jewish people?" Hence: the half-shekel represents membership in the people, and the ten commandments represents the nuts-and-bolts actions.